# How to get the user's new page selection in a Notebook control under Windows?

Tags: wxwidgets

In my app, when a user has made changes to the data on one page of my notebook control, I want to prompt them to save or discard their changes when they switch to a different page.  I have bound the `EVT_BOOKCTRL_PAGE_CHANGING` event for this, and have created a handler method.

However, I can't tell what page the user is switching to.  According to [the wxBookCtrlEvent docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_book_ctrl_event.html#af2721f1f6e9d6e5b83612f03ef36c4b5),

> under Windows, **GetSelection()** will return the same value as **GetOldSelection()** when called from the `EVT_BOOKCTRL_PAGE_CHANGING` handler and not the page which is going to be selected.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: @SueDNimme, do you actually want to prevent a selection if the user says "NO"? You can use EVT_BOOKCTRL_PAGE_CHANGED as well...

Comment: Yes, if the user had edited data on the page, and they switch to certain other pages, their changes would be discarded.  I want to prompt the user--- ask whether they really want to navigate away.  If no, the `EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGING` event would be vetoed.  I don't believe `EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED` can be vetoed, because (sfact) the change has already happened.

Comment: @SueDNymme, but you are here talking about different functionality. You can catch the page changing event and ask if they really want to change it. And then on page changed event ask if they want to save the data. If they don't its just the way it is. User choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess as a workaround, you could use a mouse handler checking for when the left button is clicked.  In a handler for that event you could do a hit test to see where the click was made and store the value of the tab that was clicked.  Something like this:

```
void MyFrame::OnLeftDown( wxMouseEvent& event )
{
    long flags;
    int ht = m_notebook1->HitTest( wxPoint(event.GetX(),event.GetY()), &flags);

    if( (flags & wxBK_HITTEST_NOWHERE) == 0 )
    {
        //store the value of ht somewhere 
    }

    event.Skip();
}

void MyFrame::OnNotebookPageChanging( wxNotebookEvent& event )
{
    //use the stored value of ht here 
}
```

Comment: That's an intriguing thought.  But I'd have to know which *tab* the user is clicking on--- is there a way to get the bounds of each tab in the notebook control?

Comment: The integer returned by the HitTest method in the code above will be the zero-based index of the tab that was clicked.  But as another answer said, if you need the index of the new tab in the PageChanging event, it's probably best to use AUINotebook instead.

Comment: This is what I wound up going with, and it worked very well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> under Windows, GetSelection() will return the same value as
>   GetOldSelection() when called from the EVT_BOOKCTRL_PAGE_CHANGING
>   handler and not the page which is going to be selected.

So, call GetSelection from EVT_BOOKCTRL_PAGE_CHANGED to get the new page.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no workaround (if there were a reliable way to do it, wxWidgets would have been already doing it), the underlying native control simply doesn't provide this information.

You can either ask whatever you need to ask the user about in any case, independently of the page they're switching to, or ask them after they will have already switched -- which is, of course, going to look weird if you then decide to switch back.

If you really, really need this functionality, you might use non-native `wxAuiNotebook` instead.